# how can I update progress bar when json data change using vue.js without refresh

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, progress-bar, reactive-programming, dashboard

I try to make a boostrap dashboard page for tracing status of my python aplication running on server.

On server side, python app update data.json file when reach certain status.
On client side, vue.js handle content creation.

I have a problem when I try to update progress bar, because i need to refresh page so that progress appears.

Any suggestion how can I make live progress bar in my view without refresh?

index.html

```
<div class="item" v-for="item in order">>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" :style="{ width: item.completion + '%' }">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    window.vue = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        name: 'Order',
        data: {
            isLoading: true,
            order: [],
        },

                created() {
                    fetch('./data.json')
                    .then((res) => { return res.json() })
                    .then((res) => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.order = res.order;
                })
            }
        })

});
```

data.json

```
{
    "order": [
        {
            "customer": "Mr. Smith",
            "price": "60",
            "status": "Pending",
            "orders": "Something",
            "completion": 40,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "isEligible": true
    }
    ]
}
```

edit: I solve my issue with adding watcher to app.js

```
            watch: {
                order() {
                    this.updateorder();
                }
            },
            methods: {
                updateorder() {
                    fetch('./data.json?_timestamp=' + Date.now())
                    .then((res) => { return res.json() })
                    .then((res) => {
                    this.order = res.order;
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```js
let i = 0;
const emulateRequest = () => Promise.resolve({
  "order": [
    {
      "customer": "Mr. Smith",
      "price": "60",
      "status": "Pending",
      "orders": "Something",
      "completion": i++,
      "isAvailable": true,
      "isEligible": true
    }
  ]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    isLoading: true,
    order: [],
  }),
  created() {
    this.load();
  },
  methods: {
    load() {
      //fetch('./data.json')
      //  .then((res) => { return res.json() })
      emulateRequest()
        .then((res) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.order = res.order;

          if (this.order.some(({ completion }) => completion !== 100)) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.load();
            }, 1000);
          }
        })
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
<div class="item" v-for="item in order">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" :aria-valuenow="item.completion" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" :style="{ width: `${item.completion}%` }">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So main difference that I created separate method which load data and if at least one order is not loaded repeat request after 1 second

Comment: I try to implement this to my code but can't figure it out work with data.json, I'll change completion manually but not effect status bar.

is there a other approach to communicate server pyton with front end js?

Sorry for my english, it's not my native.

Comment: I think you may have problem with cache, so your data.json is cached on client side(browser), to check it add random get parameter, e.g.:
`fetch('./data.json?_timestamp=' + Date.now())`

Comment: I make it work finally with using proper watchers. Thank you for your help. (: